# LowLatencyAudio plugin: Where to call unload function referred to an audio file?

Tags: jquery, audio, cordova

I used LowLatencyAudio plugin in phonegap build to play sound and which works fine . But, when I referred [this](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap/) which says, unload function must be used in order to unload an audio file from memory. Otherwise, you will cause memory leaks.
Here is my working code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PGLowLatencyAudio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script>
var lla;
var url_start = 'sounds/startup.wav';
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
   if( window.plugins && window.plugin.LowLatencyAudio)
     {
     lla  = window.plugins.LowLatencyAudio;
     lla.preloadAudio(url_start, url_start, 1, success, fail);
     }
}

function play_startup(){
 lla.play(url_start);
} 
</script>

//From main.js
play_startup();
```

My QUESTION is where I need to call **unload** function ? Is there any other way to avoid memory leaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution from [here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-lowlatencyaudio/tree/master/docs)

```
 // After completing play
 // stop after 1 min 
 window.setTimeout( function(){
    //lla.stop( click_sound );
    lla.stop( music_mp3 );

    lla.unload( music_mp3 );
    lla.unload( click_sound );
 }, 1000 * 60 );
```